# Decompose $A=D+N$ with $DN=ND$, $N$ nilpotent, $D$ diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Can anyone help me out with the following question:

For the matrix $A$ give a diagonalizable matrix $D$ and a nilpotent matrix $N$ so that $A=D+N$ and $ND=DN$.

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
-1 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

I started with finding the Jordan normal form and I got: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
0 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}$
So than J=D+N with D the diagonal matrix and $N=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$. and $A=PJP^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
10 & -1\\
5 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}*P ^{-1}$
But what are the matrices so that $A=D+N$? And how to compute $A^n$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ after that?

Comment: Is $D$ being  diagonal imply $MDM^{-1}$ diagonal for some invertible matrix $M$?? Is $N$ being  Nilpotent imply  $MNM^{-1}$ Nilpotent for some invertible matrix $M$??

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Now you have $A= PJP^{-1}=P(D+N)P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}+PNP^{-1}$. Is $PDP^{-1}$ diagonalizable? Is $PNP^{-1}$ nilpotent? Do these two matrices commute? Once you have checked this, can you use these facts to find a simple expression for $A^n$ for any $n\geq1$?